# Two loops but one doesn't run until the first one has gone through its loop in SAS?

Tags: macros, sas, do-loops

SO i have dates and codes. I want to take one month of data from a table. Go through that data in a selective manner of every two days. I am trying to match the data with another table and only match based on the data being within two days of each other.

Right now it is taking a month of data per code1 then  matching for two days then taking another month of data per code2 then matching for another two days instead of taking a month of data per code 1 matching  that whole month by going through it every two days then once the month is finished it goes through another month of data per code2.

```
%let month='01JAN2016'd;
%macro queryLoop(startDate=, i=);


    %macro loop(Code1, Code1_B);

    %let p = %sysfunc(countw(&FACLNBR, %str( )));
    %do i=1 %to &p;
        %let O_Code1= %scan(&Code1, &i, %str( ));
            %let Code1_B = %scan(&Code1_B, &i, %str( ));
```

Body of Code: // this takes a month of data to prepare for matching requirement

```
Proc sql; 
    Create table Pool_of_data_month as 
      Select t1.match_requirement1, 
             T1.matchRequirement2,
             T1.MatchRequirement3,

From database.table as t1
Where (O_Code1 = &Code1) AND (datepart(BEGINDATE) BETWEEN &month AND &month+30);
```

/////////////////////////////////////// This should loop through increments 
of data above with every two days. That is what "Between startdate and startdate +2 is doing.

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Matched_BY_THREE AS 
   SELECT t1.match_requirement1, 
                 T1.matchRequirement2,
                 T1.MatchRequirement3, 
                 t2.match_requirement1, 
                 T2.matchRequirement2,
                 T2.MatchRequirement3,
             FROM WORK.filtrate_matches t1
        LEFT JOIN WORK.FILTER_FOR_QUERY_FOR_TESTING_AHC t2 ON 
             (t1.requirement1 = t2.requirement2) AND 
             (t1.requirement3 = t2.requirement2) and 
            (datepart(t1.importantdate) BETWEEN &startDate AND &startDate+2)
    QUIT;
////////////////////////    




%end;
    %mend; 
    %loop(code1 code2 code3 code4, code1_b code2_b code3_b code4_B); 
//code1 and code1_b are a pair 


%mend queryLoop;

data list_of_dates;
i=1;
format date date9.;
do Date = '01JAN2016'd to '31JAN2016'd; //when 31JAN is hit loop again
string = catt('%queryLoop(startDate=', date, ', i=', i, ');');
call execute(string);
i+1;
output;
end;
run;
```

I have tried switching around the loops no luck.  How do I tell SAS to go through the whole month and then switch codes after.

Comment: Sample data would help make your issue clearer.  Can you post some sample input and what output you want?

Comment: @Tom Let's pretend I am trying to count how many people per website are loggimg in 2 in 2 days, but there is no way to know that they are the same person except for 3pieces of the same data that appear within 2days of one another. So if someone logs onto a sit3 and we know that they are tall skinny and red and they login again we will know and it will be a match because it will be within two day and those three similarities will be the same. Then I want to count how often this happens for any single person.  For efficiency purposes I want to go through one site (code) for a month. switchcode

Comment: Just make up some dummy data, otherwise anyone trying to help you will need to make up the data themselves.